# ranger chain commands in config

Tags: bash, files, scripting, configuration, ranger

I am using ranger as my terminal file manager and now that I understand the basics, I wanted to get a bit deeper into customizing the rc for my purposes. One thing I like to do is to map a command to a keybind that copies a template into the current folder and then starts the `rename_append` command, (usually called with keybind `a`) on the file.

Here is an example:

```
map NS shell cp ~/.templates/bash.sh . ; rename_append
```

The problem is, that no matter how I call the command, it does copy the template in my current directory, but then doesn't start the rename-process. When I quit ranger, the errormessage says that `rename_append` wasn't found, but in the ranger-config, the same command is used to rename files before the appendix. My theory is that, since I am using shell, the command tries to find `rename_append` in my programs. I don't know how to chain commands in my ranger-config where one is a shell-command and the next one isn't.

Currently I have to use a second keybind after the first and I would like to only use one and automatically go into renaming-mode after copying the file.

I hope, my problem is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `chain` command to execute multiple commands.

```
chain <command1>; <command2>; ...
```

This part is probably not relevant anymore but for the copy and rename task I came up with this solution:

```
map NS chain shell cp ~/.templates/bash.sh .; console shell mv bash.sh%space
```

This binding can be used by pressing NS, typing the new file name followed by pressing enter.
This solution does not use `rename_append` because it executes the command on the current selection and I couldn't get the selection to change.

Answer (score 0):

I have been running in the same kind of issue (without the shell component):
I tried to map `D` to do what `.d.!` does, that is hiding directories.

In the default config

- `.d` maps to `filter_stack type d`
- `.!` maps to `filter_stack not`

So I tried to chain both by mapping `D` as such :

```
map DD filter_stack add type d ; filter_stack add not
```

When I try this I get a red `'type'` in the console output.

In both cases it seems that the `;` is not correctly interpreted but while in your shell case, there is an ambiguity in the meaning of the `;` (is it end of shell command or end of ranger mapping command ?), in my case there should be no ambiguity.

Still, it seems that whatever is added after `type d` is interpreted as the continuation of the `d` type and it generates an error, I guess because of a resulting incorrect type (neither '`d` ' nor '`d;`' are valid types).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/442854)